# HTTP_Request: malformed response

Tags: php, curl, pear

When i try open connection `HTTP_Request` throws:

> Malformed response:
>   `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Only if site located on the same server as script.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

```
<?php
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$hosts = array('http://example.com', 'http://site_on_my_vps.com' );
$status = array();

foreach($hosts as $host){
    $request = new HTTP_Request2( $host , HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
    $status[ $host ] = array( );

    try {
        $response = $request->send();
        $rbody = $request->getBody();

        $status[ $host ]['status']= $response->getStatus();
        $status[ $host ]['bodysize']=strlen( $rbody );

    } catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
        $status[ $host ]['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
}


print_r($status);
```

upd: add code

Comment: Please add the 1-3 lines of the related code so it is more clear to what that relates to. Are you using a HTTPS link?

Comment: The response is malformed. Monitor the response with a network sniffer, check if something is obviously wrong with it.

Comment: "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", content-length etc. is valid...